# MySQL: is a comparison with an integer faster than with a varchar field?

Tags: mysql, indexing

In a table 'test' I have an integer field TestID, with an index.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE TestID=1234

SELECT * FROM test WHERE TestID='1234'

SELECT * FROM test WHERE TestID=COALESCE(1234, 0)

SELECT * FROM test WHERE TestID=COALESCE('1234', '')
```

I use the second option now, because in my application the `1234` part is inserted dynamically, and could also be NULL or and empty string, and I don't want the statement to fail because of that.

How much would the speed difference between those statements be or is there no difference at all?

Comment: answer to title question : yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TestID column is unindexed then varchar will be slower than integer. But if this field is indexed there will be practically no difference in speed.

P.S. if your strings are really long - index will be more bulkier so in that case using integer will be more preferably

Comment: the field is stored as an integer (mediumint) , so the index can never become too bulky, right?

Comment: Exactly. The phrase about values length relates to varchar fields. Integers for sure will be at least not slower.